# Segment routing with JUNOS MX routers

Tags: routing, juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-mx

I'm trying to configure segment-routing with Juniper MX routers. but i can not find much documentation related with that. if anyone have configuration guide i ll be appreciate.

thanks.

Comment: Another common name for segment routing is SPRING (Source Packet Routing in Networking) - I saw some pages by using that as another search term.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: This probably may help you - [link](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/example/example-configuring-spring-srgb.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic for SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 1):

Juniper now have a Day One guide on it, which should rapidly see you master it.

https://www.juniper.net/us/en/training/jnbooks/day-one/configuring-segment-routing-junos/index.page

There has been a fair amount of discussion of it on the juniper-nsp mailing list, too.

Comment: Link-only answers are not what we are looking for. This is an archive, and links go bad over time. You should put the relevant content in your answer, and provide the link for attribution/backup and further reading.

Comment: Thanks, Ron - given the topic is quite literally a book-length discussion, and the Day One guides are likely to be available long term, noting the existence of the resource seems warranted. But thanks for the note on the intended content and standards. :) Taken another way, the question is too broad :)

Comment: If the question requires an answer that is so large, then the question is too broad for this site, and it should be flagged as such. In any case, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic for SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se].